# Error while installing Angular?

Tags: angularjs, npm, installation, windows-nt

I'm trying to install Angular but some errors occurred. Please, refer to
this image

[image]

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In general, it's better to include the text output of your problem rather than images.  Either way, your problem may be related to a proxy server as suggested here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7519

Comment: Also, make sure you are running the install as administrator.